# Proving $ \Bigg( \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{ \lambda_i x} P_i(x) = 0 \Bigg) \implies \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}, P_i = 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

I'm trying  to prove $$ \Bigg( \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{ \lambda_i x} P_i(x) = 0 \Bigg) \implies \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}, P_i = 0 $$
as $ \lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n $ are n distinct real numbers and $ P_1, \ldots, P_n $ are n polynomial functions.

I found this problem on my math textbook; my trusty induction method doesn't get me anywhere. How should I proceed?

Comment: The intuition is that the exponential growth beats the polynomial growth. This mean the largest $\lambda_i$ determines the growth for $x\rightarrow \infty$. This then implies that the polynomial that corresponds to that $\lambda_i$ must be identically zero as this is the only polynomial which vanishes in the limit $x\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Let me be a bit more precise. Wlog we may assume that $\lambda_1$ is bigger than any other $\lambda_k$ with $k\in \{ 2, \dots, n\}$. Then we can divide the equation by $e^{\lambda_1 x}$ and get $$ P_1(x) + \sum_{k=2}^n e^{-(\lambda_1 -\lambda_k)x} P_k (x) = 0$$ Using that the sum goes to zero for $x\rightarrow \infty$ we get $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} P_1(x)=0$ which implies $P_1$ is the zero polynomial.